# Quadratic equation roots function

Tags: c

**The problem**

Write a function that calculates the real and imaginary roots of the quadratic equation

```
ax^2 +bx+c = 0
```

You should handle the three types of roots.

Hint: use this function prototype:

```
int calculateRoots(int a,int b,int c,float* root1,float* root2);
```

My questions:

- how can a function solving quadratic equation returns an int? I am clueless on what that means
- I changed the fuction return type to `void()` but I couldn't handle the 2 imaginary roots not sure how to return real+imag i

Here 's what I reached so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void calculateRoots(int a,int b,int c,float* root1,float* root2);
    int main()
    {
        float r1,r2;
        int a,b,c;
        printf("enter the coefficients :\n");
        scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
           void calculateRoots(a,b,c,&r1,&r2);
        printf("%d and %d are roots,r1,r2);
        return 0;
    }
    void calculateRoots(int a,int b,int c,float* root1,float* root2)
    {   float x=b*b-4*a*c;
        if(x==0)
        {
            *root1=(-1*b)/(2*a);
            *root2=(-1*b)/(2*a);
        }
        else if(x>0)
        {
            *root1=(-1*b+x)/(2*a) ;
            *root2=(-1*b-x)/(2*a) ;
        }
        if(x<0)
        {
            root1=// Any help here
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like something you should ask your instructor. Were you given sample inputs/outputs for each case?

Comment: You are probably not asked to handle imaginary roots. You probably need to handle the 3 cases, exactly one root, two roots, no roots at all. If `x < 0` return 0 otherwise return 1. That way the caller can know that there are no roots if the function returns 0.

Comment: `float *root1` can point to an ***array*** of floats. So the function is called like this: `float r1[2], r2[2];  calculateRoots(a,b,c,r1,r2);`  The return value is either 1 or 2, i.e. the number of roots.

Comment: @Kevin no sample run was given..this is all the assignment

Comment: @techi the hint says: _use this prototype `int calculateRoots(int a,int b,int c,float* root1,float* root2);`_  for a reason. Consider my first comment.

Comment: @user3386109 I considered the same possibility, but I don't think we can safely make these assumptions. techi needs to ask their instructor.

Comment: The teacher may want the students to think creatively. The hint with the prototype was certainly given for a reason.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Only one way to find out :). Asking questions (within reason) is better than making assumptions and being wrong.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thank you so much! you changed the way I thought about the problem ..

Comment: @techi another possibility: the function could return the number of roots (0,1 or 2).

Comment: @MichaelWalz that's what I did

Comment: The return value should indicate whether the roots are real, imaginary or non-existent (`a` is zero; there aren’t two roots because it isn’t a quadratic equation).   Then the pointer arguments either return the two toots or the real and imaginary parts. At least that is consistent with the assignment. Alternatively, you could pass two arrays of size two and treat each as a complex number, and assign the results accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A variation to Daniel Sęk's hints:

As the rules for solving quadratic equations (w. real coefs) are quite simple you can use the two `float` arguments in the prototype just as you did.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int calculateRoots(int a, int b, int c, float *root1, float *root2);

int main(void)
{
  float r1, r2;
  int a, b, c;
  int ret;

  puts("enter the coefficients a, b, c:");
  ret = scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
  // always, An I mean _always_ check the returns of scanf!
  if(ret != 3){
     puts("No, the three coeficients, please, and they have to be integers. Try again.");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  ret = calculateRoots(a, b, c, &r1, &r2);
  // the function returns a value that is eather the sign of the
  // determinant or an error.
  switch (ret) {
    case 0:
      printf("r1 = r2 = %f\n", r1);
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("r1 = %f and r2 = %f\n", r1, r2);
      break;
    case -1:
      printf("r1 = %f + %fi and r2 = %f - %fi\n", r1, r2, r1, r2);
      break;
    default:
      puts("No roots found, check input");
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}

int calculateRoots(int a, int b, int c, float *root1, float *root2)
{
  float x;
  // shortcut: check for a== 0
  if (a == 0) {
    return -2;
  }
  // find determinant
  x = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  fprintf(stderr, "determinant is: %f\n",x);
  // checking if a float is exactly equal to a number is highly problematic!
  if (x == 0.0) {
    *root1 = (-1 * b) / (2 * a);
    *root2 = *root1;
    return 0;
  } 
  // macro avaliable with c >= c99
  else if (isgreater (x , 0.0)) {
    *root1 = (-b + sqrt(x)) / (2 * a);
    *root2 = (-b - sqrt(x)) / (2 * a);
    return 1;
  }
  // macro avaliable with c >= c99
  if (isless(x , 0.0)) {
    // not the nicest way possible, but good enough if documented:
    // put the real part in one variable, the imaginary part in another,
    // return the sign and let the caller sort it out.
    *root1 = -b / (2 * a);
    *root2 = sqrt(-x) / (2 * a);
    return -1;
  }
  // notreached
  return -3;
}
```

C99 and later has complex numbers. You might use those instead.

Comment: Why using `-b` for both the roots?

Comment: @R15 Because that's how I got taught in school (see e.g.: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-functions-equations/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-formula-a1/a/discriminant-review Just the first in a Google search). Oh, I just saw that it is called "discriminant" and not "determinant" which is something completely different (I'm not a native speaker, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

> how can a function solving quadratic equation returns an int

You should return number of roots, so leater you would know how many roots to print.

> I couldn't handle the 2 imaginary roots not sure how to return
>   real+imag

I assume (**but maybe @deamentiaemundi is correct, because for this problem you really have only two different numbers that, with the help of function return value, allow to reconstruct valid result, and after reading your question once again, wording may suggest it**), you are expected to use two element arrays:

```
float resultRoot1[2];
float resultRoot2[2];
int numRoots = calculateRoots( a, b, c, resultRoot1, resultRoot2 );
```

Inside `calculateRoots`

```
root1[0] = real_part;
root1[1] = imaginary_part;
```

For example, given

```
2x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0
```

you should return

```
-0.5 - 0.5i
-0.5 + 0.5i
```

so `resultRoot1` should contain values `-0.5`, `-0.5` and `resultRoot2` values `-0.5`, `0.5`.

---

Beyond your asigment (for future considerations) you can try use structs

```
struct ComplexNum
{
    double re, im;
};

int calculateRoots( int a, int b, int c, struct ComplexNum* root1, struct ComplexNum* root2 )
{
    ...
    root1->re = real_part;
    root1->im = imaginary_part;
    ...
    return num_roots;
}
...
struct ComplexNum resultRoot1, resultRoot2;
int numRoots = calculateRoots( a, b, c, &resultRoot1, &resultRoot2 );
```

or even better complex header

```
#include <complex.h>

int calculateRoots( int a, int b, int c, double complex* root1, double complex* root2 )
{
    ...
    *root1 = real_part + imaginary_part * I;
    ...
    return num_roots;
}
...
double complex resultRoot1;
double complex resultRoot2;
int numRoots = calculateRoots( a, b, c, &resultRoot1, &resultRoot2 );
```